# SQL Agent schedule in different time zones

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL Agent job running on a server using UTC time zone for a client in Eastern Daylight Savings (actually multiple clients across the US).  I need the job schedule to 'adjust' appropriately for the client(s). I can calculate the difference in hours between UTC & Eastern before creating the job, but when Daylight Savings starts (or stops) it will be wrong.  Ideally, I would be able to designate a time zone when creating a SQL Agent Schedule, but I don't know of a way to do that. Several posts for SQL Server 2005 & 2008 basically say this isn't possible. (Best suggestion I saw was 2 jobs running at different times of the year.)  I'm hoping this has been somehow addressed with SQL Server 2014 or 2016.

Comment: Similar question at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882138/how-to-change-sql-job-to-different-time-zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882138/how-to-change-sql-job-to-different-time-zone).