# How to change SQL Server Agent job to different time zone

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

I have SQL Server Agent job and i want to change the time zone to a different time zone

Comment: There's not enough detail here to answer your question. Are you using a scheduling utility (if so, what)? Do you mean datetime logic in your queries? (If so, what DBMS and what date logic?).

Comment: There is no such thing as a "SQL job" - are you talking about a "SQL Server" job? SQL is a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database"

Comment: I have an Indo-European verb. How do I conjugate it in the past tense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're asking about a schedule on a SQL Server Agent job, SQL Server Agent uses the timezone of the host machine.  You have to either change the timezone of the host machine that the SQL Server instance is running on or manually make the adjustment in the job schedule.

Comment: I only want to change one SQL Server Agent Job  time zone.

Comment: Like I said, you have to do it at the host or set the time on the schedule manually taking the time zone difference to the host time zone into account.  You can't set the time zone on a per job basis.

Comment: i am on Job Schedule properties and i can not find option for different time zones.

Comment: Again, you can't set the time zone on a schedule.  If you are in Eastern time and your schedule is to start at 1:00 PM Central then you need to set the schedule to start at 2:00 PM.  Schedules are in the time zone of the host server.  I can't make it anymore clear than that.